# Scrapy code no longer works after adding a proxy

Tags: python, web-scraping, proxy, scrapy, response

I am trying to scrape patents like this one:
https://patft.uspto.gov/netacgi/nph-Parser?Sect1=PTO2&Sect2=HITOFF&u=%2Fnetahtml%2FPTO%2Fsearch-adv.htm&r=1&f=G&l=50&d=PTXT&p=1&S1=7844625.PN.&OS=pn/7844625&RS=PN/7844625

After writing a scraper for this type of patents and trying it on a small sample, everything was fine besides getting blocked. So, I added a proxy by Bright Data and I tried to run it again, but my selectors no longer worked. I get errors on code that worked before adding the proxy, such as this one:

```
    patent['number'] = response.xpath('//html/body/table[2]/tr/td[2]/b//text()').getall()[0].replace(',', '')
    patent['date'] = cleaned(response.xpath('//html/body/table[2]/tr/td[2]/b//text()').getall()[1])
```

Findings:

1. The page seems to change, as I observed using PyCharm's debugging tool. It seems like the '\n' characters are appearing everywhere, or they are moved. You can see there is a difference in capitalization:
   without proxy: response capitalized

See these here:

[top: with proxy; bottom: without proxy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31duo.png)

2. I also observed that there are some differences in bytes:
   with proxy, the response is 41059 bytes
   without proxy, the response is 40353 bytes

Any ideas on how to make the scraper work on the response content given by the proxy? Thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

Which network type are you using? ASN from datacenter looks to be blocked, have you tried with residential proxies?

During my test datacenter was unsuccessful whereas some residential was a success.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! It worked, but now the issue is that is wayy to slow for what I need. I was using webunlocker before trying residential